# Disable all workflows for specific instance of entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I would like to be able to disable all workflows for a specific instance of an entity. Say for example a Lead. We have found a lot of situations where this would be helpful like with migration, manually fixing external system errors etc.

For now the only way I can see is adding a check to every workflow and a field to the entity. My question: is there an easier way to stop the workflows from running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. When you deactivate the workflow, it becomes deactivated for all instances for that entity. So... if you need to disable it for a specific record then you'll need a condition check basically.

In relation to data migrations, one thing we do, sometimes, is deactivating the workflow temporarily (assuming you can do that) for something like a bulk update for instance where we don't want workflows triggering for that (like, sending emails and spamming people :P ).

That's assuming you can afford deactivating some workflows temporarily, cause if that's a 24x7 service, it won't be possible and your best option is adding check conditions.

Hope this helps

Comment: I already thought this would be the only solution. I was just hoping there would be a better one as it seems to me that this is not a very uncommon situation.